# SWIFT best practice to share variable across view controllers and inside class functions

Tags: swift, closures, global

I guess I have traced down the issue of the error **Instance member 'txtProblem' cannot be used on type 'TextProblemViewController'**, however, I wonder what is the best practice on how to deal with the underlying issue.

I have a global data structure **TextProblems** which I use to fetch JSON data. This data is used by multiple view controllers. That is why I declared it as a global variable

```
var problems:TextProblems!

class TextProblemViewController: UIViewController {
```

Now I wanted to break my viewDidLoad() apart and moved some code to a separate function, thus

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  do {
    problems = try readJsonProblem()
  } catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
  txtProblem.text = fillParamters(textRaw: problems.textProblem[i].problemStmnt.problemText, parameters: problems.textProblem[i].problemStmnt.problemPrmtr.map {$0.param})
```

became

```swift
let ProblemStmntView: UIView = {
  let view = UIView()
  view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
  view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  txtProblem.text = fillParamters(textRaw: problems.textProblem[i].problemStmnt.problemText, parameters: problems.textProblem[i].problemStmnt.problemPrmtr.map {$0.param})
  return view
}()
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  do {
      problems = try readJsonProblem()
  } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
  view.addSubview(ProblemStmntView)
```

This results in the above error message at the line **txtProblem.text = fillParameters**, where txtProblem us an IBOutlet of a label
I have seen 3 resolutions and imagine a 3rd one - and I guess there are more:

1. declare the variable as static (but this does not work outside a class when declaring the global variable
2. make the variable lazy, however, I think I cannot declare an IBOutlet as lazy
3. pass the data from viewDidLoad to my closure (the example showed passing it to a function as a solution), however, not sure how to pass the data to the initialization closure
4. declare the global variable as static within the structure

So my question is, what do you assume to be best practice when sharing data not initialized before run time across view controllers and class functions? Would you declare a global variable or somehow pass along the data between view controllers, functions (and initialization closures???)?

Comment: best practice is to use MVVM. You should not be passing data from one controller to the other, but save it in the Model, which is independent from how it's represented by UI, and can be used by various VCs in different ways. In your case you need something like `TextProblemsModel`, which loads and stores that array, as well as any other state variables, so when you navigate between VCs, there;s nothing for you to pass between them, each simply renders the view based on current state of that model. See: https://www.raywenderlich.com/34-design-patterns-by-tutorials-mvvm

Comment: Thanks @KirilS. I saw MVVM mentioned before but did not follow the lead. I'll try to adopt the data flow to this concept and I hope that this will also solve my issue. But in any case, this layering should help once the data and the app becomes more complex

Comment: @KirilS. One more "thing": Currently my top structure is defined as `struct TextProblems: Codable {
    var textProblem: [TextProblem]
}`, to read all JSON data into an array. So for MVVP, would I build my view model based on a non-array structure and would then parse the JSON into a variable `var data: [textProblem]` defined outside the data class (inside the view controller, the view model or wherever)?

Comment: you will have the same textProblem array as now, BUT not inside the controller, rather inside data model/data source class.